# Problem with action region and apex:actionfunction

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

i am using action function as i need values of form in my controller after an on change event is fired.but there are some required fields also.when i change some value in dropdown action function is called and it gives the required validation error on other required fields .when i fill them and again onchange event is fired ,i get the changed value in backend.but i want that it should avoid the required validation error on other fields for that i use immediate="true " with action function but now it does not gives required error but in my controller method i did not get values.whats the reason for that .how can i overcome this?

```
<apex:actionRegion >
    <!-- Displaying Personal Data section -->
    <apex:repeat value="{!contactInformation}" var="contact" rendered="{!contactInformation.size>0}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!ContactFields}" var="contactInfo">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Contact Information">
                <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="current">
                    <apex:inputField styleClass="country" label="Country"  value="{!contact[current.fieldPath]}" onChange="dynamicConditions();" required="{!OR(current.required, current.dbrequired)}"/>  
                 </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>          
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
    <apex:commandButton title="Save" value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:actionFunction name="dynamicConditions" action="{!dynamicConditions}"/>
```

Comment: Your action function is outside of action region. Did you try bringing in that?

Answer (score 6):

Buried in the order of execution for visualforce postback requests section of the docs is this nugget of information:

> During a postback request, the view state is decoded and used as the
>   basis for updating the values on the page. Note: A component with the
>   immediate attribute set to true bypasses this phase of the request. In
>   other words, the action executes, but no validation is performed on
>   the inputs and no data changes on the page.

So if you use immediate, it doesn't just skip the validation, it also discards the user input.

I think your problem should be solved by moving the actionFunction inside the actionregion - otherwise it will be posting back the entire form, including any required fields, rather than just your selected components.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using another approach in which all the necessary parameters are passed as apex param.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="myFunc" action="{!dynamicConditions}">
        <apex:param name="param1" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

To call apex action method use following javascript

```
myFunc("myvalue1", "myvalue2", ...);
```

Inside apex action method use following code to get value of param

```
String param1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
```